# IIS Url Rewrite Module - Error with plus add character

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite, iis, url-rewriting, query-string

I have a problem using + (plus add) character in iis url rewrite module.

I need to rewrite:

http://www.example.com/search/test1+test2

in

http://www.example.com/search/?q=test1+test2

Url rewrite module basic solution doesn't work and throw a 404 error:

Pattern: **^search/([^/]+)/?$**

Rewrite URL: **search/?q={R:1}**

=============================

I try adding another parameter but I throw a 404 error again:

Pattern: **^search/([^/]+)\+([^/]+)/?$**

Rewrite URL: **search/?q={R:1}+{R:2}**

=============================

This alternative solution for example works:

Pattern: **^search/([^/]+)-([^/]+)/?$**

Rewrite URL: **search/?q={R:1}+{R:2}**

What's the problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I think you dont need the `^` in the beginning

Pattern: `search/([^/]+)/?$`

Rewrite URL: `search/?q={R:1}`

Comment: Thanks but this is not the problem